# "Warning for exceptional heat" or should it be "temperature"?

Tags: word-choice

The UK suffered from very high temperatures on 18 and 19 July 22. The word 'heat' rather than 'temperature' was widely used in describing the situation.  For example, the Health Security Agency has a document [“Heatwave plan for England”](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1091292/Heatwave_Plan_for_Engand_2022_July_2022.pdf) which has the strap line

> Heatwave plan for England. Protecting health and reducing harm from
> severe heat and heatwaves.

And a headline from the [Met Office](https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/about-us/press-office/news/weather-and-climate/2022/red-extreme-heat-warning) states

> For the first time temperatures of 40°C have been forecast in the UK
> and the Met Office has issued the first ever Red warning for
> exceptional heat.

Would not 'temperature' be a better choice than 'heat'?

Answer (score 2):

Definitions may help in this case:

> temperature:
> **Degree** of hotness or coldness of a body or environment

> Cold:
> **Sensation** produced by low temperatures

> heat:
> **Sensation** produced by high temperatures

> heatwave:
> A wave of unusually hot weather

> coldwave:
> A wave of unusually cold weather

Main Points:
(1) We sense the heat but measure it by temperature ; hence "heat" is better in that government Document.
(2) Heat permits Heatwave , temperature will not allow temperaturewave.
(3) "Severe (or Extreme) temperature" by itself will not indicate whether it is hot or cold.
(4) Met Office is reporting the "Degree" of heat and correctly uses "temperature" in the measurement.

Comment: Not sure why you're capitalizing Degree, Heat, Hence, etc, but you have thecorrect distinction between heat and temperature.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmatory comment , @StuartF ! I sometimes use Caps to place "gentle emphasis" & avoiding "bold" , but yes , it is "nonstandard" & idiosyncratic !!